# HTML Image Gallery Not Showing Images

Tags: html, image, slideshow

I recently put an image gallery slideshow on my website. I put all the images in and tested it on my browser and it works fine.

However, when I uploaded the website to my server, some of the images do not show up. Here is the code below. Images 1,4, and 6 show up fine. However, 2,3, and 5 do not show up at all. I am very confused by this. They worked when I tested them in my browser. Now that they are uploaded, its not working properly.

Image Sizes:
1: 124kb
2: 617
3: 668
4: 139
5: 1610
6: 830

Does anyone have any suggestions on what might be causing this?

Thanks in advance!

```
<center><h1>Gallery</h1></center>
<ul data-orbit data-options="timer_speed:99999; bullets:false;">
<li>
<img src="img/slider/slide1.jpg" />
<div class="orbit-caption">caption here...</div>
</li>
<li>
<img src="img/slider/slide2.jpg" />
<div class="orbit-caption">caption here...</div>
</li>
<li>
<img src="img/slider/slide3.jpg" />
<div class="orbit-caption">caption here...</div>
</li>
<li>
<img src="img/slider/slide4.jpg" />
<div class="orbit-caption">caption here...</div>
</li>
<li>
<img src="img/slider/slide5.jpg" />
<div class="orbit-caption">caption here...</div>
</li>
<li>
<img src="img/slider/slide6.jpg" />
<div class="orbit-caption">caption here...</div>
</li>
```

Comment: did you check image existence with absolute address in browser ?

Comment: Check names of slides carefully! If you have tested on Windows locally, Win is case insensitive. Linux (if you are testing on Linux online) - is case sensitive. So, uppercase or lowercase is important.

Comment: Thank you for the advice @nevermind although I checked and they are all lowercase this is something I did not know and will take into account later.

Comment: Go have a look in the Network panel of your browser’s developer tools – it will show you what image requests generate errors. If it’s 404s, then you did _not_ specify the image paths/file names correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the permissions of the files to read-only